# PyCharm Error, Try and Except

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pycharm, try-catch

I have written a small program for my CS class.  I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why it wouldn't work.  When I pasted my code into Trinket.io, it worked!  The problem is that the try and except still does not work in PyCharm.  I am using the latest version and verified that it is set to Python 3.  Just looking for a possible cause and solution.  I would try another IDE but the class requires using PyCharm and that is what the professor uses to grade the projects.  Thank you.

```
# This is a guess the number game using the random module
from random import randint
import sys

randomnum = randint(1, 101)  # set random number between 1 and up to but not including 101
guesses = 0  # Starting Value for Guesses

while guesses != randomnum:  # while loop to allow for multiple guesses
    guesses = input("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100, Take A Guess: ")  # get users guess

    try:
        guess = int(guesses)  # Convert Guesses to An Integer

    except ValueError:
        print("You Did Not Enter A Valid Number! ")
        sys.exit()

    if guesses == randomnum:  # If player gets it correct
        print("You Guessed My Number !!! ")

    elif guesses < randomnum:  # Tells the user their guess was too low
        print("Too Low ")

    elif guesses > randomnum:  # Tells the player their guess was too high
        print("Your Guess is Too High ")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an error message? Does just nothing happen? Does it run but you get an unexpected result? We need more details to help you effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the latest python version, I think its 3.7, and then make sure that the correct python interpreter is set for the project. If you need more help, comment!

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get everything working.  It just does not work in PyCharm.  I do have the latest Python installed and it works at command line, just not in PyCharm.